# Window not found Error , Implementing Multi thread concept for modal window

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

Previously I faced an issue with Modal window’s in my project. And I have resolved the issue by implementing Multi-Thread concept. i.e., I have created a new thread before clicking to any element, which will evoke a modal window.

In the `run()`, I have wrote set code which will select a value from the modal window. And modal window will get closed automatically after clicking any value from the list.

code snippet

```
public class MyProj implements Runnable {

static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Thread t;

MyProj() {

    // Code to create a Thread
}

public void run() {
    // Code to select a option from the Modal window
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, FindFailed, InterruptedException {

     driver.get(...); 

     // Code ......... 

     new MyProj(); //Calling Constructor to create a new thread

     driver.findElement(...).click(); // click to open modal window     

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // Getting error at this point
```

After the successful execution of method `run` , when I tried to execute `driver.getTitle()`, to know where the control is now ,getting an error as

“Window not found. The browser window may have been closed”.

How to overcome from this error?? Kindly help !

Comment: I know nothing of selenium, but what I know about GUIs in general is that they tend not to work at all with multiple threads.

Comment: selenium does not support modal dialogs from the browser; although it apparently somewhat works in IE. If you swap over to a non-browser dialog (e.g. a jquery dialog), then you should be able to get past this issue.

Comment: @Petesh : hai , After selecting any one option from the modal window, window will get closed automatically, i'm not sure how i can swap my control to a non-browser diaglog .

Comment: @MikeNakis: Thnx for your input.

Comment: @SivashankarMani if you're using window.showModalDialog, then, as I mentioned, [selenium doesn't allow for automating it](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284). There are some suggested workarounds in the issue mentioned. I don't know how you would swap to a non-browser dialog either; it was a throwaway comment to suggest other avenues to address the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to start a Thread.Give it a try ! I tried in my system it is working fine.Let me know if you face any issue.

```
MyProj() {
t = new Thread(this);
t.start();
}
```

Comment: Hi , I also used the same to create a Thread , t = new Thread(this, "Second Thread"); , if there anything i can to get this issue rid out ??

Comment: I tried your code it seems to be working fine. Are you using driver object in run method ?

Comment: Yes, Im using driver in run method. used driver.findelement for locating elements in modal window.